# SSH Variable not passing

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

I am having trouble making this work and am looking for some help.

Currently i have a file dumped into my directory every day with the date as the file name (say "100928.zip") and I am trying to setup a cron job to unzip it but figured i'd test it first.

Using OSX Terminal.

**This is what I am doing....**

iDate='date +%y%m%d';
unzip -uod domains/mydomain/directory/$iDate;

**However I get an error...**

unzip:  cannot find or open +%y%m%d, +%y%m%d.zip or +%y%m%d.ZIP.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use backticks (`` ` ``) to execute the command and put its return in the variable.

```
iDate=`date +%y%m%d`; unzip -uod domains/mydomain/directory/$iDate;
```